# wacom bamboo ink plus won't stay connected to Bluetooth on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, wacom, bamboo

My wacom bamboo ink plus won't stay connected to Bluetooth on Ubuntu 22.04. If I put the Wacom into pairing mode it is identified and I can connect it, but it then immediately disconnects.

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 7306 2in1, it is dual boot between Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04. The same hardware works fine on Windows 11, with the Wacom connected by Bluetooth.I therefore believe this issue to be software rather than hardware related.

I have the following Wacom related packages/libraries installed to support the pen;

- libwacom-bin 2.2.0-1
- libwacom-common 2.2.0-1
- libwacom9 2.2.0-1
- xserver-xorg-input-wacom 1.0.0-3ubuntu1

I have the following Bluetooth related packages/libraries installed;

- bluez 5.64-0ubuntu1
- bluez-cups 5.64-0ubuntu1
- bluez-obexd 5.64-0ubuntu1
- gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0 42.0-5
- gnome-bluetooth 3.34.5-8
- gnome-bluetooth-3-common 42.0-5
- gnome-bluetooth-common 3.34.5-8
- libbluetooth3 5.64-0ubuntu1
- libgnome-bluetooth-3.0-13 42.0-5
- libgnome-bluetooth13 3.34.5-8
- libldacbt-enc2 2.0.2.3+git20200429+ed310a0-4
- pulseaudio-module-bluetooth 15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2

Currently the stylus acts like a mouse, it is not pressure sensitive, and to write with it, I have to hold down the equivalent of the left mouse button.

Any pointer on how I can get this stylus working properly under Ubuntu, would be gratefully received.